# "Let me complete, please" vs "Let me finish, please"

Tags: phrase-meaning

Let's suppose that someone is being interrupted while speaking and, therefore, having to ask another person to stop interrupting them:

> "Let me complete, please."
>
> "Let me finish, please."

Do both phrases sound natural? Are there any differences in meaning?

Comment: *Complete* needs an **object** of the completion: "Let me complete **my speech**, please." *Finish* doesn't. You'll be familiar with "Let me finish" if you're married.

Comment: @user105719 Thank you! But what do you mean by familiar if married?

Comment: Sorry, bad (attempted) joke. Everyone who's been married long enough has had an argument with the spouse in which one person says to the other "Stop interrupting me, and let me finish!"

Comment: @user105719 Got it)) Thanks!

Comment: The British 'politician', Nigel Farage, has become famous for saying 'Let me finish!' at every opportunity, even when no-one is interrupting him.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first sentence is ungrammatical because "complete" needs a direct object. For example, you can say *"let me complete my sentence"*. "Finish" doesn't need a direct object, so the second sentence is fine.